# Show XML file in RichTextBox without Tags

Tags: c#, xml

I want to show my XML file as a paragraph in rich text box 
with out any tags

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("practical1.xml");
       // XmlNodeType type;



        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText("<");
                    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Brown;
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(reader.Name);
                    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(">");
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText("</");
                    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Brown;
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(reader.Name);
                    this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText(">");
                    this.richTextBox1.AppendText("\n");
                    break;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to show my XML file in rich text box but with out any tags ... is it possible ?

Comment: Sure, something is possible.  1) What does your XML look like?  2) For that XML, what do you want to see in the rich text box?  3) What have you tried, and why isn't it working?

Comment: I have converted the Word file (.DOCX) into XML file 1) In my XML file there are a lot of paragraphs , I just want to display those paragraphs in rich textbox.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, because it seems that, in order to achieve what you want, simply remove the part in your `switch` where you add the tags..